# OP accidentally omitted return keyword. Why was typographical error flag declined?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24688159/3303195) was posted recently, and another user quickly spotted that the OP had omitted the `return` keyword in (what would be) their function's return statement.  The OP even commented on the answer, confirming the omission was the problem and that it was merely accidental (versus a lack of understanding that the keyword is necessary, which would then at least *arguably* make the question useful). So I flagged the post as off-topic as the problem was a simple typographical error. But the flag was declined, and while I disagree with the decline, I'm more curious to know the rationale behind the decline.  There was no "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it” or other comment accompanying the decline.

So, why was the flag declined? Is it a matter of mechanics? I am wondering if the OP accepted the answer before a mod reviewed my flag, and if the presence of an accepted answer voids flags of this nature.

I have done some searching around, so if there is an FAQ or already a post with a detailed explanation on this kind of scenario and I've missed it, I do apologize.

Comment: Repwhores (err.. _enthusiasts_) wouldn't let you close questions (especially trivial typo ones) easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flags for closure go to the Close Review Queue and are handled by the community (anyone with [3k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can review).

As 3 people there [voted with *Leave Open*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5271983), your flag was automatically marked declined.

When the question is presented in the queue, the answer is not visible. Comments *are*; had you left a comment on the post calling out the issue the voting could well have gone the other way.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I had imagined that the entirety of the post (question, answers, and comments to all) was available to reviewers. It would seem to me answers would be especially of use during review given the nature of the flag.  With that in mind, a comment seemed a bit superfluous on my part, but I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: The entirety is available to the reviewer through a link, but only limited information is automatically displayed. Personally, unless the issue is really obvious I do click the link and look over the answers.

Comment: @faintsignal Reviewers are asked "should this be closed as off-topic", but do not see the off-topic reason unless they click *close*. Arguably, the interface could be improved.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier If you click the `(more)` next to the listed close reason it will show you which off topic close reason was chosen while in the review queue.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may want to leave a comment before voting to close.  The close review system does not show answers (you have to go to the question to see that), so reviewers may not see what you see.

It is never a bad idea to be explicit in a case like this.